# How can I alter an HTML button's output based on time of day?

Tags: javascript, html, button, time

I have click counters set to work during different times of day. I'm trying to have the counters all respond from the same HTML input, in my case it's a button. Essentially if the button is pressed during timeN (shown below), it should output via Slot 1. If it's not clicked during that period, it should output via Slot 3.

I already have the code for different counters, and the times of day set to variables. I try calling them similarly to what's shown in my example below:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    let Slot1Cntr = document.getElementById('SL1').innerHTML;
    let Slot2Cntr = document.getElementById('SL2').innerHTML;
    let Slot3Cntr = document.getElementById('SL3').innerHTML;

    function addCntS1(){
            Slot1Cntr++;
            document.getElementById('SL1').innerHTML = Slot1Cntr;  
    };
    function addCnt2(){
            Slot2Cntr++;
            document.getElementById('SL2').innerHTML = Slot2Cntr;  
    };
    function addCnt3(){
            Slot3Cntr++;
            document.getElementById('SL3').innerHTML = Slot3Cntr;  
    };

    const timeN = now.getHours() === 19;
    const timeNN = now.getHours() === 20; 

    function switchCounter() {
            if (timeN) {
                return addCntS1();
            } else if (timeNN) {
                return addCntS2();
            } else {
                return addCnt3();
            };
        };

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button onClick="switchCounter()" type="submit">Destruct Earth</button>
            <h1><i>Slot 1</i></h1>
            <h1><span id="SL1">0</span></h1>

            <h1><i>Slot 2</i></h1>
            <h1><span id="SL2">0</span></h1>

            <h1><i>Slot 3</i></h1>
            <h1><span id="SL3">0</span></h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like it if a press of the Destruct Earth button yields to "Slot 3" unless the time is aligned with const's timeN and timeNN, which would be 7 & 8 PM respectively. Any feedback would be appreciated

Comment: When you run your code, check the web console. It should show you that you have some errors. You are calling `getElementById` before the elements are rendered on the page. Also, tell us what happens when the button is clicked currently.

Comment: it appears you are using a variable called now that isn't defined, do you mean `Date.now().getHours()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this with your javascript and it worked for me.

```
let Slot1Cntr = "";
let Slot2Cntr = "";
let Slot3Cntr = "";

window.onload=function(){
      Slot1Cntr = document.getElementById('SL1').innerHTML;
      Slot2Cntr = document.getElementById('SL2').innerHTML;
      Slot3Cntr = document.getElementById('SL3').innerHTML;
    }    

    function addCntS1(){
            Slot1Cntr++;
            document.getElementById('SL1').innerHTML = Slot1Cntr;  
    };
    function addCnt2(){
            Slot2Cntr++;
            document.getElementById('SL2').innerHTML = Slot2Cntr;  
    };
    function addCnt3(){
            Slot3Cntr++;
            document.getElementById('SL3').innerHTML = Slot3Cntr;  
    };

    var now = new Date();

    const timeN = now.getHours() === 19;
    const timeNN = now.getHours() === 20; 

    function switchCounter() {
            if (timeN) {
                return addCntS1();
            } else if (timeNN) {
                return addCntS2();
            } else {
                return addCnt3();
            };
        };
```